# Vert.X webclient progress state

Tags: java, upload, progress-bar, vert.x

I like to upload a lot of big files (100MB-1000MB) to a webservice. Therefor I´d like to use the webClient with sendMultiPartForm to avoid urlencoding. It´s necessarry to give the user feedback about the progress. How can I achieve this. Get the progress state that I can calculate the remaining time for upload?

Or has someone an example of a download progress with vertx webclient, that I can adopt it?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the sources and I think the API currently doesn't provide that functionality directly.

Although I haven't tried it myself, [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel) looks quite convenient. It explicitly mentions multipart and file uploads. I've also seen progress callbacks on byte level ([look here](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/tree/master/fuel))!

I'm sure there are other solutions (pure Java, even other Kotlin), too.